# PHP __call() function - what to do with the rest of the methods

Tags: php, call, pass-through

I'm writing a class that uses `__call()` to handle some magic functions, with no parent class, I can't find a syntax that allows me to pass responsibility on to methods *not* handled by my `__call()` implementation:

```
call_user_func_array([$this, $methodCalled], $arguments) //- infinite loop
call_user_method_array($methodCalled, $this, $arguments) //- infinite loop
parent::__call($methodCalled, $arguments) //- doesn't work if I don't *have* a parent (or even if I do have a parent, if that parent doesn't define __call())
```

I've run out of ideas for how to handle this case and google is not being my friend :-(

Comment: Well, what do you *want* to happen? `__call` handles all calls that could not be resolved to other methods. It is already the fallback delegate. Where else do you want to delegate those calls to?

Comment: If you need ever a `__call()` in OOP, then your design is broken

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    switch($method) {
        case "MethodA":
            // handle it
            break;
        case "MethodB":
            // handle it
            break;
        default:
            $parent = get_parent_class();
            if ($parent && (method_exists($parent, $method) || method_exists($parent, '__call')))
                return parent::__call($method, $args);
            else
                trigger_error("Call to unhandled __call function $method()", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

You can place it in child and parent classes. If a call is left unhandled in a child, the child will look if its parent can handle it and otherwise trigger an error.